# Matlab - Updating a Listbox to show new data

Tags: matlab

The goal of this is simply to store the name the user gives to the drawing they make into the listbox so they can see a history of what they have done e.g. 
1) user draws a line and calls it 'firstline' so listbox shows 'firstline'
2) user then draws a rectangle and calls it 'rectangle' so listbox shows 'firstline'
                                                                         'rectangle'

The relevant code I have so far looks like this.

```
 name = inputdlg('Enter a name for the Object', 'Line Name');

        %get the current list box contents and store to a handle array
        handles.currentHistory = get(handles.historyList, 'String');

        %now add the name the user enters to this array
        handles.currentHistory(size(handles.currentHistory)+1) = name;

        %now update the history list
        set(handles.historyList, 'String', handles.currentHistory);
```

The output of this is fine for the first one but then proceeds to go something like the following which assumes 3 objects being called first, second and third.

first

second
second

third
second
third

I'm struggling to understand why its outputting in this way and wondered how I could simply get it to update.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
handles.currentHistory{end+1} = name; % add element after the last one
```

For this you have to initialize `handles.currentHistory` properly:

```
handles.currentHistory = {};
```